# Android socket behaviour after screen_off

Tags: android, sockets

**Situation:**
I'm developing an Android app using a socket for communication with a server via the websocket protocol.
The starting point to open the socket is a Service started from the application context. Opening and communicating with the server works fine.

**Problem / Question:** 
The socket is not closed, when the device is going in mode SCREEN_OFF.
So my question / concern is, what is really going on with my process when the device is in such power state? Should i react and close the socket to save battery? The websocket is also using ping/pong mechanism to keep the connection alive. So if the system never "stops" my process i will always communicate until the battery is down or the OS kills my app?
Or am i understanding something wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When device go in sleep mode, you have to close all service, thread to save battery.

Comment: So wifi or gsm is still "alive" and sockets are open when device is in mode SCREEN_OFF?

Comment: yes you could receive SMS or call when device is in sleep mode